# XSLT Transformation: Search nodes, and return hierarchical parents

Tags: xslt, hierarchy, transformation

hoping this hasn't been asked before, but I have the following XML:

```
<Company id="1000" name="Company1000">
   <Company id="1020" name="Company1020" />
   <Company id="1004" name="Company1004">
      <Company id="1005" name="Company1005" />
   </Company>
   <Company id="1022" name="Company1022" />
</Company>
```

I have the following XPath to search for nodes: `//*[contains(translate(@name, "ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), "005")]`

I would like this to return:

```
<Company id="1000" name="Company1000">
   <Company id="1004" name="Company1004">
      <Company id="1005" name="Company1005" />
   </Company>
</Company>
```

So this matches the Company1005 node, and all its respective parents. I would like the above to also be returned if I were searching for "100", which in that case, would match each element in turn, but I clearly don't want duplication of nodes.

I've been struggling with this for hours now, so your help will be much appreciated!!!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with _duplication of nodes_?

Comment: Xsl 1.0 please. And by duplication, I just meant that if it matches both parent and child, that they should remain in the same place they were in the original doc. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to copy only descendant or self nodes which match your requirement (containing the string you want).

Look this picture at the bottom of this [page](http://nwalsh.com/docs/tutorials/xsl/xsl/foil22.html) for the XPath axes you need.

Long version:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- Default: copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- just copy Company which descendant-or-self contain the matching string -->
<xsl:template match="Company">
    <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::Company[contains(translate(@name, 'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '005')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Short version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- Default: copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- do not copy Company which do not have a descendant-or-self matching string -->
<xsl:template match="Company[not(descendant-or-self::Company[contains(translate(@name, 'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '005')])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output of your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Company id="1000" name="Company1000">
  <Company id="1004" name="Company1004">
    <Company id="1005" name="Company1005"/>
  </Company>
</Company>
```

Comment: That's beautiful, thank you. I can't test this at the moment, but as soon as I do, I'll make this my answer. Thank you so much.